# Changing array values in C produces "undefined reference to 'memset'"

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, compiler-errors, riscv

I am initializing a 32-element array of 1s and 0s for the starting state for a Game of Life in C. When I use this line:

```
int board[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
               0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
```

there are no issues compiling. However, when I simply change the values in the array, and not the length or declaration of the array:

```
int board[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

the code does not compile, instead producing an "undefined reference to 'memset.'". Here is the error I get when compiling:

```
[ubuntu@swell-dipper:~/OS/assiqnment2/c-and-assemblvA] $ make
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -O -march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 -g -c main.c -o main.o
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -O -march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 -g -c lib.c -o lib.o
riscv64-unknown-elf-as -march=rv32im -g -c calc_val.s -o calc_val.o
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -O -march=rv32im -mabi.ilp32 -g -c simulation.c \
  -o simulation.o
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -nostdlib -o simulation -Map simulation.map \
  -T demo.lds crt0.0 main.o lib.o calc_val.o simulation.o
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: main.o: in function 'main':
/home/ubuntu/OS/assignment2/c-and-assembly/q2/main.c:23:
  undefined reference to 'memset'
make: *** [Makefile:58: simulation] Error 1
```

How could the same exact code, simply with different values for the elements of the array, not be able to be compiled? I also never use anything in regards to `memset` in the code anywhere.

I have tried a few different values for the elements of the array, and it is on and off whether or not the code compiles.

Comment: Show [mcve]s (one that works and another one that doesn't work). And don't post pictures of text, post text as text.

Comment: Please post your entire code so we may be able to gain more insight into your problem.

Comment: Perhaps it is some optimization that gets triggered by a large enough string of identical bytes in the initializer. I assume this `int board[]` variable is on the stack?

Comment: This paragraph in [section 2.1 of the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) is relevant: "*Most of the compiler support routines used by GCC are present in `libgcc`, but there are a few exceptions. GCC requires the freestanding environment provide `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset` and `memcmp`. Finally, if `__builtin_trap` is used, and the target does not implement the trap pattern, then GCC emits a call to `abort`.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running `ld` yourself.  This is almost always a mistake.  Use the `gcc` "compiler driver" to link, and remove `-nostdlib` and `crt0.o` from the linking command line, and the problem should go away.

What's *happening* is that the compiler has probably chosen to generate code for the second array initialization as if you had written

```
int board[32];
memset(board, 0, sizeof board);
board[K] = 1;
```

where K is the position of that single 1 in your array initializer.  This is perfectly permissible; the C standard says that the compiler is allowed to generate calls to *any* C library function, even if they did not appear in the source code.  You can make GCC *less* inclined to do this by using the `-ffreestanding` command line option, but it will not completely eliminate these "synthetic" calls.  [Section 2.1 of GCC's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) specifically points out that even in `-ffreestanding` mode, it may generate calls to `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset` and `memcmp`.

GCC may also generate calls to functions in its *own* internal runtime library, whether or not it's in freestanding mode.  These are used for things like arithmetic operations that the hardware doesn't provide instructions for.

When you use the compiler driver to link, the C library, the internal runtime library, and some "startup files" that handle stuff like C++ global constructors are automatically included in the link, so all this is invisible to you.   Using `ld` bypasses that and exposes the fact that code generation needs these things even if you think it doesn't.  You *can* in principle use `gcc -v` to find the names of all the extra implicit stuff and add back only the bits you need, but it's almost certainly easier to just use the compiler driver to link.

Comment: Great answer, +1, I had no idea about this. I can imagine that errors caused by insertions into the source code by the compiler would be very hard to find if you didn't know they could.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense that not including the standard library is causing an issue--this is for a school assignment, so I didn't write the Makefile.